# how to add datetimepicker dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Is there a way wherein i can add datetimepicker dynamically on my page? I was able to add the form elements however the datepicker functionality is not working.

Here's the form layout

Screenshot 1: http://i614.photobucket.com/albums/tt226/civicclubphilippines/1_zpswf7pxjxz.png
Screenshot 2: http://s614.photobucket.com/user/civicclubphilippines/media/test/2_zpspzjdb7yb.png.html

HTML Code

```
        <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-another"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add another</button>
    </div>
```

JS code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".add-another").click(function(){

        var assgnee = $('#assigneeInit').html();

        var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);
        $(".add-another-container").append('<div class="form-group"><hr>'
           +'           <div class="col-md-4"></div>'
           +'           <div class="col-md-6">'
           +'                 <input required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Task name" type="text" size="50" name="taskname[new][]" id="taskname" value="">'
           +'                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>'
           +'           </div>'
           +'            <div class="col-md-4"></div>'
           +'           <div class="col-md-6">'
           +'             <textarea required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Task description" name="task-description[new][]" id="task-description" rows="2"></textarea>'
           +'             <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>'
           +'           </div>'
           +'           <div class="col-md-4"></div>'
           +'           <div class="col-md-6" id="assigneeCol"><select required class="form-control" name="assignee[new][]" id="assigneeInit'+rnd+'">'+assgnee+'</select>'
           +'             <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>'
           +'           </div>'
           +'            <div class="col-md-4"></div>'
           +'           <div class="col-md-6">'
           +'             <input placeholder="Due date" class="date-picker-manual datepicker hasDatepicker" type="text" name="due-date[new][]" id="datepicker'+rnd+'"><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" id="trigger'+rnd+'" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="...">'
           +'           </div>'
           +'         </div>');


          $(".datepicker").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            //dateText comes in as MM/DD/YY
            var datePieces = dateText.split('/');
            var month = datePieces[0];
            var day = datePieces[1];
            var year = datePieces[2];
            //define select option values for
            //corresponding element
            $('select#month').val(month);
            $('select#day').val(day);
            $('select#year').val(year);
            }
          });

      });


  });
```

i need to add the dynamically added datepicker with concatenated id values from from the variable rnd

Is there anyway to achieve this?

Suggestions and answers are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There is a inbuilt Calendar in jQuery UI, you can look into that ..

Comment: Initialize the datepicker after DOM is appended..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
+'<input placeholder="Due date" class="date-picker-manual datepicker" type="text" name="due-date[new][]" id="datepicker'+rnd+'">'
+'<img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" id="trigger'+rnd+'" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="...">'
```

You need to remove a class `hasDatepicker` from the input control and after append you can put the datepicker initialization code.

---

#### Note:

`hasDatepicker` is the class added when your target element is a datepicker but if you have this class added to your element then this element will be ignored by jQuery/jQueryUI to intialize it as datepicker, so **`hasDatepicker` should not be added to the element**.

Answer (score 0):

As `@Jai` already mention you need to remove `hasDatepicker` since the date picker is yet to be added. intialize the `datepicker` after append.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $(".add-another").click(function(){

         var assgnee = $('#assigneeInit').html();

         var rnd = Math.ceil(Math.random()*1000);
         $(".add-another-container").append('<div class="form-group"><hr>'
            +'           <div class="col-md-4"></div>'
            +'           <div class="col-md-6">'
            +'                 <input required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Task name" type="text" size="50" name="taskname[new][]" id="taskname" value="">'
            +'                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>'
            +'           </div>'
            +'            <div class="col-md-4"></div>'
            +'           <div class="col-md-6">'
            +'             <textarea required="" class="form-control" placeholder="Task description" name="task-description[new][]" id="task-description" rows="2"></textarea>'
            +'             <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>'
            +'           </div>'
            +'           <div class="col-md-4"></div>'
            +'           <div class="col-md-6" id="assigneeCol"><select required class="form-control" name="assignee[new][]" id="assigneeInit'+rnd+'">'+assgnee+'</select>'
            +'             <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>'
            +'           </div>'
            +'            <div class="col-md-4"></div>'
            +'           <div class="col-md-6">'
            +'             <input placeholder="Due date" class="date-picker-manual datepicker" type="text" name="due-date[new][]" id="datepicker'+rnd+'"><img class="ui-datepicker-trigger" id="trigger'+rnd+'" src="images/calendar.gif" alt="..." title="...">'
            +'           </div>'
            +'         </div>');
             $(".datepicker").datepicker();
       });

       
}); 


</script>
<div class="add-another-container"></div>
<div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default add-another"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add another</button>
    </div>
```